# Algorithm for shortest path in c # to global coordinates

Tags: c#, algorithm, google-maps

Hi I 'm working on a program that displays maps in these metro stations , each station I have their coordinates are shown . I have to do is indicate start a station and a destination and find the shortest route but not how to implement them just having the coordinates of each station.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "but not how to implement them just having the coordinates of each station"? If you want to implement a shortest route algorithm, check out Dijkstra's algorithm. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: Another (possibly easier) way is to use the Google Maps API, as it will find the shortest route for you with coordinates.

Comment: For geographical routing, see [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)